# Photos deleted on iPhone got deleted in Google Photos - Recovery?

Tags: photos, iphone, google

I synced all photos and videos from my iPhone 6 to Google Photos. I then turned off "Back up & sync" in Google Photos, deleted all photos and videos on my phone, and discovered this also deleted everything in Google Photos.

I've already deleted everything from "Recently Deleted" on my phone. Is there any way to recover my photo and videos? Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

From [Google Photos Support](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6128867?co=GENIE.Platform%3DiOS&hl=en&oco=0)t:

> 1. Open the Google Photos app .
> 2. At the top left, tap Menu , then Trash .
> 3. Touch and hold the photo or video you want to recover.
> 4. At the top right, tap Restore . That photo or video will be restored to your Google Photos library and added back into any albums it was in.